# how do i check the data in an array with indexOf in java

Tags: java, arrays, indexof

i'm fairly new to java and i'm trying to use indexOf to check if a persons name ends with the letters in the array and output a word it rhymes with. Where am i going wrong? e.g. Dean ends in "ean" so it rhymes with green. Thanks guys

```
    String [] first = new String [3];
    first [0] = "eem";
    first [1] = "een";
    first [2] = "ean";

    for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {

        if (first[i].indexOf(first.length) != -1){
            System.out.println("That rhymes with green");
        }
    }
```

Comment: see my code, let me know if I am missing something. Just run it directly on my machine, its working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [endsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) instead of [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)). `indexOf` will return the index where the passed string exactly matches the current string and, as the name suggests, `endsWith` will check if the current string ends with the passed string.

Take a look at the following code:

```
String personName = "Dean";
String[] suffix = {"eem", "een", "ean"};
String[] names = {"greem", "green", "grean"};

for(int i = 0; i < suffix.length; i++) {
    if (personName.endsWith(suffix[i])){
        System.out.println("That rhymes with " + names[i]);
    }
}
```

Also, ideally, you would want to keep a map of `suffix -> name` for maintainability, but for simplicity/exploring this should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! what great community to be apart of :)

Answer (score 2):

To check with weather the input contains any array given element's, you should receive `input` and then iterate over your array to look at. For ex

```
  String personname = "Dean";
  String [] first = new String [3];
    first [0] = "eem";
    first [1] = "een";
    first [2] = "ean";

    for (int i = 0; i < personname.length; i++) {    
        if (input.indexOf(first[i]) != -1){  // check my input matched
            System.out.println("That rhymes with green");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just to piggyback this. OP the reason your code is breaking is because you are testing the contents of your `first` array against the length of the array. `first[i].indexOf(...)` will cycle through "eem", "een", and "ean" and check to see if there is a character equal to the length. So you're checking in your code whether "eem" has a 3 in it and not whether the input has an "eem" in it.

Comment: How is the question's part addressed that OP wants to know if the input is *ending* with some of the rhymes in the other array?

Comment: @FabianBarney is right. The listed code would say that "Deanery" rhymes with "green". the OP should use endsWith() instead of indexOf().

Comment: @FabianBarney OP stated that `i'm trying to use indexOf to check if a persons name ends with the letters in the array and output a word it rhymes with`, I may be wrong here too :)

Comment: If he wants to do indexOf to meet a requirement and can't use endsWith() then they can test indexOf(first[i]) == input.Length() - first[i].Length()

Answer (score 0):

I have tested and ran it on the compiler. This is working fine. Please comment for any quesions. Thanks

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld
{

    public static void main(String []args)
        {
            String [] first = new String [3];
            first [0] = "eem";
            first [1] = "een";
            first [2] = "ean";

            /* I am trying to get the input from user here */

            String s;
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the string:");
            s = in.nextLine();

            /* Now, String.indexOf(substring) will check the condition if the match happens it will print the output, if it doesn't it returns -1 */

            for (int i = 0; i <s.length(); i++) 
                {    
                    if (s.indexOf(first[i]) != -1)
                        { 
                            System.out.println("That rhymes with green");
                        }
                }

       }
}
```